# Help Implementing a 4-qubit super dense coding algorithm

Tags: quantum-circuit

I am new to quantum computation, I have seen examples of super-dense coding; however, I am struggling in my attempts to scale the 2-qubit system to a 4-qubit, here is a visual of the 2-qubit super-dense coding protocol I have implemented. My question is could anyone please provide an explanation on scaling in general. [image: 2-qubit super-dense coding protocol]

Comment: related paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0407193.pdf

Comment: To scale to $2n$ qubits, you just repeat the 2 qubit case in parallel (i.e. on different qubits) $n$ times.